# Automatic date in pivot in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

As I am less aware of `Stored Procedure` can anyone help me out with automatic date in `pivot` as I want the user to select `start date` and `end date` and I want to display all the selected dates as horizontally. As till now I am using dynamic dates by writing dates in pivot but I want it to display all the dates from the start date to the end date automatically.

Can anyone help me?

As it should display `date as 01,02,03,04,05 up to the end date`

Comment: pls. add your required output.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Most dbms have their own versions of stored procedures.)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you cannot.  The column names are part of the query.  Dynamic is the way to go, but be careful - dynamic results from SPs are difficult to consume.  You might want to rethink and go traditional row-based doing the pivot in your front end.